# Chart.js Charts using static data not rendering, possibly due to Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am currently creating a website with the Vue.js framework as a project and I am trying to display data with some graphs from the Chart.js library, initially I assumed I was doing something wrong so I tried to create a chart on a blank webpage, which I got working pretty quickly. I then ported the code over to my existing project which uses Vue.js and could not get the charts to render. I have made sure that the id of the canvas element matches.

I was looking for a solution the other day and I came across a post of a forum that said that it was because Vue has control over the code and so it doesn't allow Chart.js to render the chart unless I declare it as a component of Vue, but I don't know what that means and I can't find the forum anymore.

I've also seen many posts about similar issues but their problem is derived from the fact that they are using dynamically changing data supplied by Vue whereas the data i'm using is static so the solutions don't work.

One thing to note is that I am trying to render the charts inside of a conditionally rendered div using v-if.

Excuse any bad or messy code especially my html styles, I know I should be using classes and I plan to go through later and clean it up.

**Chart.js**

```
let userStatsLine = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
let groupStatsPie = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");

let lineGraph = new Chart(userStatsLine, {
    type:'line',
    data:{
        labels:['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Nov','Oct','Dec'],
        datasets:[{
            label:'Individual Total Completions',
            data:[1,2,2,4,5,7,8,10,13,17,18,20],
            backgroundColor:'#7fbaf1',
            borderColor:'#7fbaf1',
        }, {
            label:'Average Total Completions',
            data:[1,3,4,6,7,9,11,14,18,19,21,23],
            backgroundColor:'#3b81c1',
            borderColor:'#3b81c1',
        }, {
            label:'Completions Per Month',
            data:[1,1,0,2,1,2,1,2,5,4,1,2],
            backgroundColor:'#f2fa96',
            borderColor:'#f2fa96',
        }, {
            label:'Average Completions Per Month',
            data:[1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,3],
            backgroundColor:'#aab062',
            borderColor:'#aab062',
        }],
    },
    options:{
        responsive:true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    color: "grey"
                },
                grid: {
                    color: "#404040"
                }
            },
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    color: "grey"
                },
                grid: {
                    color: "#404040"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

var names = ['Incomplete','Sally','Thomas','Ansh','Edmund'];

let pieGraph = new Chart(groupStatsPie, {
    type:'doughnut',
    data:{
        labels: names,
        datasets:[{
            label:'Individual Total Completions',
            data:[33,21,11,25,20],
            backgroundColor: names.map((l, i) => i ? '#7fbaf1' : '#f2fa96'),
            borderColor:names.map((l, i) => i ? '#3b81c1' : '#aab062'),
            weight: 0.6 
        }],
    },
    options:{
        responsive:true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
              labels: {
                generateLabels: () => [{
                  text: 'Incomplete',
                  fillStyle: '#f2fa96',
                  strokeStyle: '#aab062',
                },
                {
                  text: 'Complete',
                  fillStyle: '#7fbaf1',
                  strokeStyle: '#3b81c1',
                }]
              }
            }
          }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div v-if="graphToggle == true" style="display: flex;justify-content: center; height: 70.1%; position: relative; margin-top: 4.05%;">
        <div class="flexRows" style="padding: 25px; background-color: #404040; width: 50%; border-radius: 15px">
            <div style="width:300px !important; height:300px !important">
                <canvas id="lineChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div style="width:300px !important; height:300px !important">
                <canvas id="pieChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script src="charts.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Vue.js**

```
class Task
{
  constructor(name, goal, due)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.goal = goal;
    this.due = due;
    this.dueDate = Math.round(Date.parse(this.due)/1000);
    this.created = Math.round(new Date()/1000);
    this.completed;
  }
}

const Tasks = Vue.createApp({
  data(){
    return{
      incompleteTasks: [],
      progressingTasks: [],
      completeTasks: [],
      name: '',
      goal: '',
      due: '',
      showTaskAdder: false,
      day: '',
      month: '',
      year: '',
      nameChars: 20,
      goalChars: 128,
      graphToggle: false,
      graphIcon: 'Assets/graph.svg',
      tempIcon: 'Assets/tasks.svg',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTask() {
      if (this.validifyDate(this.day, this.month, this.year) == true)
        this.due = (this.day+'/'+this.month+'/'+this.year);
      if (this.name.length > 0 & this.goal.length > 0 & this.due.length > 0)
      {
        this.incompleteTasks.push(new Task(this.name, this.goal, this.due, this.incompleteTasks.length-1));
        this.goal= '';
        this.name = '';
        this.due = '';
        this.clearDate();
      }
    },
    progressTask(status, position) {
      if (status == 0)
      {
        this.progressingTasks.push(this.incompleteTasks[position]);
        this.incompleteTasks.splice(position, 1);
      }
      if (status == 1)
      {
        this.updateCompletionDate(position);
        this.completeTasks.push(this.progressingTasks[position]);
        this.progressingTasks.splice(position, 1);
      }
    },
    regressTask(status, position) {
      if (status == 2)
      {
        this.removeCompletionDate(position);
        this.progressingTasks.push(this.completeTasks[position]);
        this.completeTasks.splice(position, 1);
      }
      if (status == 1)
      {
        this.incompleteTasks.push(this.progressingTasks[position]);
        this.progressingTasks.splice(position, 1);
      }
    },
    updateCompletionDate(position) {
      this.progressingTasks[position].completed = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);;
    },
    removeCompletionDate(position) {
      this.completeTasks[position].completed = null;
    },
    isLeapYear(year) {
      if (year % 4 == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        if (year % 100 != 0)
        {
          if (year % 400 != 0)
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
    getBounds(month, year) {
      if (month == 4 | month == 6 | month == 9 | month == 11)
        return 30;
      else if (month == 2)
      {
        if (this.isLeapYear(year) == true)
          return 29;
        else
          return 28;
      }
      else
        return 31;
    },
    clearDate(){
      this.day = '';
      this.month = '';
      this.year = '';
    },    
    validifyDate(day, month, year) { 
      try
      {
        day = parseInt(day);
        month = parseInt(month);
        year = parseInt(year);
        if (isNaN(day) == true | isNaN(month) == true | isNaN(year) == true)
        {
          return false;
        }
        if (month < 1 | month > 12)
        {
          this.clearDate();
          return false;
        }
        if (day < 1 | day > this.getBounds(month, year))
        {
          this.clearDate();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
      catch
      {
        this.clearDate();
        return false;
      }
    },
    toggleGraph() {
      this.graphToggle = !this.graphToggle;
      let temp = this.graphIcon;
      this.graphIcon = this.tempIcon;
      this.tempIcon = temp;
    }
  }
})

Tasks.mount('#tasks');
```

Comment: Where is location of js code ?

Comment: Be sure what **graphToggle** is true before starting to run the script.

Comment: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/

Comment: @MichalLevý wouldnt advise using that wrapper atm, since it still not updated to support v3 of Chart.js and doesnt seem like there is any effort being made in updating it and since op is using v3 he would need to downgrade again

Comment: @Radeanu I have a button that toggles it but I didn't want to just dump the entire html file there, i can see that the canvases are there because I have their background colour set to a different colour than the background, they just aren't rendering. ill add my vue code to the original post.